# Can't use an added column in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a table with for example 2 columns, then I altered the table and added a third column `ManagerID` is successfully added.

But when I call it in the query, I get this error:

> invalid column name

Code:

```
-- This is example from the start.. please read it and tell me 

CREATE DATABASE PortEmp

CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Salary INT NOT NULL,
)

-- Now I executed the code and table and database is added successfully 

ALTER TABLE Employees
ADD ManagerID INT NOT NULL

-- Now I executed the alter command and it's been added

SELECT Name FROM Employees

-- I use select for name successfully 

SELECT ManagerID FROM Employees

-- Now there is a red line under managerID
```

Comment: When the batch is compiled, the column doesn't exist. So you can't refer to it until the next batch, or you can execute the next section of the query via dynamic sql

Comment: but i simply created a table then altered it... why i can't call the new column !

Comment: For the reason Charlieface explained - if you run the alter in one batch and the select in another it will work.

Comment: sorry but am very new to database, how i go to another batch?

Comment: and it's very strange cause i did it before ! altered a table then used the column,, i can't understand the problem

Comment: You can run the alter table command in a query window, then once run, delete it it, and run your select.

Comment: Please note the code formatting option in the editor.

Comment: @MohamedAzzam, add a `GO` after `ALTER TABLE`. SSMS sends the preceding statements to SQL Server as a single batch whenever a `GO` batch terminator is encountered. Note that `GO` is only recognized by SQL Server tools like SSMS and SQLCMD.

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring during the *compilation* of the code.  T-SQL compiles a batch before it is executed.  During the compilation phase, all the identifiers are resolved.

All three lines are being compiled at the same time. The third statement fails because the second statement -- although *compiled* has not been *executed* -- so the column does not exist.

One solution is dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT FirstName FROM Employee;

ALTER TABLE Employee ADD ManagerID INT NULL;

EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT ManagerID FROM Employee';
```

Dynamic sql doesn't compile the expression until it is executed -- so all the previous statements have been compiled *and executed*.

It should also work to put `GO` between the statements:

```
SELECT FirstName FROM Employee;

ALTER TABLE Employee ADD ManagerID INT NULL;
GO

SELECT ManagerID FROM Employee';
```

Comment: the problem is that.. it's not an error during compiling.. it puts a red line under ManagerID and tell me it's invalid column name as it doesn't even exist

Comment: @MohamedAzzam . . . That is a "compilation" error.  The column doesn't exist when you write the code.  You have to run it to add the column.

Comment: I swear i did, and i see the column name in the left as a column of EmpData table,,, but still i can't use it in select,, tells me it's is invalid

Comment: i checked, and i am connected to the same database.. i can use the original columns,, but the added one is the problem

Comment: i wanna put a command.. where to put it ?

Answer (score 0):

When the batch is compiled, the column doesn't exist. So you can't refer to it until the next batch, usually separated with `GO`.

Every batch or stored procedure is compiled by SQL Server at the start of execution, so you get a compile error.

Or, you can execute the next section of the query via dynamic SQL, like so:

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'

SELECT 1; -- or whatever
-- don't forget this is text, not code, and you need to escape quotes
-- for example:
SELECT ''hello'';
-- Do also use parameters properly, like so:
SELECT @myParam;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@myParam varchar(20)', @myParam = @myParam;
```